# How to use 'User' as foreign key in Django 1.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, foreign-keys, django-users

I have made a custom profile model which looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

But when I run `manage.py syncdb`, I get:

> myapp.userprofile: 'user' has a relation with model User, which has
>   either not been installed or is abstract.

I also tried:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractUser
```

But it gives the same error. Where I'm wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Is "django.contrib.auth" in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py ?

Comment: This one seem to work: 'user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)'. However not sure what's difference.

Comment: The difference is that for a OneToOneField, a user can have only one profile (which is probably what you want).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Change this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('User', unique=True)
```

to this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more clear if we used `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey` with `unique` constraint.

Comment: beware: If you do this and later on try to extend your User model creating a custom user model, you will need to change it to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as Anton Strogonoff said in his - more correct IMO - answer

Comment: Use `OneToOneField` if your relation is one to one, and add `primary_key=True`

Comment: For newer versions of Django, ForeignKey requires you to specify `on_delete=models.CASCADE` or another [on_delete option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Answer (score 62):

Exactly in Django 1.5 the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting [was introduced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model), allowing using a custom user model with auth system.

If you're writing an app that's intended to work with projects on Django 1.5 through 1.10 and later, this is the proper way to reference user model (which can now be different from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

- See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) for more details.

In case you're writing a reusable app supporting Django 1.4 as well, then you should probably determine what reference to use by checking Django version, perhaps like this:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


def get_user_model_fk_ref():
    if django.VERSION[:2] >= (1, 5):
        return settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    else:
        return 'auth.User'


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model_fk_ref())
```

Comment: I changed the code to note treat the version number as a decimal number. After all, the version 1.10 is considered higher than 1.5, which is not true if we treat them as decimal numbers.

Comment: @Flimm Looks good to me, didn’t like that dance with the decimals anyway. Tuple comparison beats it (maybe slightly less intuitive but it works!)