# Django: Extending 'User' via OneToOneField - Accessing first_name

Tags: python, django, model

When I extend the Django `User` using a `OneToOneField` to create a `Manager`, the  form to create a `Manager` in Django Admin only has fields for username and password.

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    """
    Users who need to login to manage the listing of a Outlet
    are represented by this model.
    """
    manager = models.OneToOneField(User)
    internal_notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.manager.username
```

What is the right way to add the other built-in `User` fields like `first_name` etc to my `Manager` model?

Comment: Look at this answer here, it explains the best way to customize and extend User.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433630/how-to-use-user-as-foreign-key-in-django-1-5/19434182#19434182

Comment: such fields are provided by Django's User class already. Also the type of User is an attribute already, if I am not mistaken, so you might want to use that. In case, simply add the fields you require to your class (i.e. Manager)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking here. The form to create a User (not a Manager) displays only three fields at first, to allow you to set the password, but then continues on to a second form where you can set other fields including first name.

Your Manager class doesn't need to define those fields, since they are attributes of the User class which you access via the one-to-one relation.

Comment: I see. I was expecting the form to create a Manager would display all the fields that Manager contained - which would include all those that User contained; in fact I am still puzzled why it displays only those 3 fields.

Comment: I don't understand what three fields you mean, actually. Your Manager form does only display the fields that Manager contains - the user (which you've called `manager`, for some reason) and `internal_notes`. All the other fields are on User itself. And the initial form for creating a user only displays username and password, it doesn't even show email at that stage.

Comment: Actually I have to unregister User first for it to work right. Why?
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User)